# Set Taxonomy Description via Rules

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, workflows

Question:
How can I access a taxonomy's description in the "Rules" module? When I create a new taxonomy entity I can only set the name of the term, I'd like to also add the term's description.

Goal (in case I'm doing this entirely wrong!):
Anonymous submission of new taxonomy terms with a description, for approval by a role. When node type of "new term" is approved, it copes it to a taxonomy vocabulary and then deletes the original node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Rules, after your Action **Create a new entity** (of type taxonomy term), when you set a new one, **Set a data value**, find *the entity you just created* -> **Description** .[image]